# Bivariate transformation using cdf method

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, mathematical-statistics, transform

Given $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 1, 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1$ and $Z = XY$ I wanted to try to get the cdf using the cdf method of transformation. I did

$$F_z(Z) = P(Z \leq z) = P(XY \leq z) = P(Y \leq z/X)$$
$$F_z(Z)=\int_0^z\int_0^{z/x} dydx$$

but evaluating this integral doesn't work because you get

$$z/x \bigg\rvert_0^z = z(\ln z - \ln 0)$$

Where am I going wrong? I assume my bounds are wrong?

Comment: where is $f(x,y)$ in the integral??? You are missing the indicator _and_ the outer integral is on $(0,1)$

Comment: @Xi'an $f(x,y)$ is just $1$ so it is in the integral right? Could you explain why the outer integral is $(0, 1)$, and even in that case wouldn't you still get an $\ln 0$? I'm very new to cdf transformation for bivariate distributions so I'm sorry if I'm missing something fundamental. Also what do you mean by indicator?

Comment: @Xi'an I added the tag

Comment: Where is your Jacobian needed to map from x,y onto z? Right now, you're not accounting for it. For edification, we will let $U = XY, V=X$, then $X=V$ and $Y = \frac{U}{V}$, and so the Jacobian should be $\frac{1}{v}$. After that, you will get the transformed joint distribution $f_{U,V}(u,v)=\frac{1}{v}$. Finally, you may find the marginal distribution of U because U equals to XY. Remember here $U=XY \le X = V$ so $f_U(u)=\int_u^1 \frac{1}{v} dv = -ln u$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the event $Y<z/X$ is integrated in $Y$, there is no further constraint on $X$: since the density of $(X,Y)$ is $\mathbb{I}_{0\le x\le 1}\mathbb{I}_{0\le y\le 1}$, the derivation goes as follows:
\begin{align*}
F_z(Z) &= \mathbb{P}(Z \leq z)\\ &= \mathbb{P}(XY \leq z)\\ &= \mathbb{P}(Y \leq z/X)\\
&=\mathbb{E}_X\left[ \mathbb{P}(Y \leq z/X|X)\right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}_X\left[ \int_0^{\min\{1,z/X\}}\text{d}y\right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}_X\left[ \min\{1,z/X\}\right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}_X\left[ \mathbb{I}_{X\le z}+z/X\mathbb{I}_{X\ge z}\right]\\
&= \int_0^z\,\text{d}x+\int_{z}^1 z/x\,\text{d}x\\
&=z+x\{\log(1)-\log(z)\}\\
&=z(1-\log(z))
\end{align*}

Comment: What does $\mathbb{I}$ mean?

Comment: This is a standard notation for indicator functions.